# Whats the better way to identify the context path in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, contextpath

I have my web application deployed to tomcat with an applicatio context. 
For example my URL looks something like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

**myapp** - is the application context here.

Now in an Angular service if i want to call a webservice say `getusers`. My URL should be this `/myapp/getusers`. But I want to avoid hardcoding the application context as it might change from one deployment to other. 
I have managed to figureout the contextpath from `$window.location.pathname` but it looks very stupid. Is there a betterway?

FYI I am using Spring MVC for restful services.

Answer (score 12):

What I have done is declared a variable in the main jsp file. Then that variable will be available throughout the angular application.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _contextPath = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
</script>
```

This code should be written in header before including other JavaScript libraries.

Comment: How to access this variable in an Angular Service ?

Answer (score 7):

I'm also using tomcat and Spring MVC. Using relative url in JavaScript will do the trick.

For doing this you just need to remove the `/` at the begining of REST url. so that your url starts from the current url in your browser.

replace `$resource('/getusers')` with `$resource('getusers')`

Answer (score 3):

Inject the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location) service to your controller.

```
 var path = $location.path(); // will tell you the current path
     path = path.substr(1).split('/'); // you still have to split to get the application context

 // path() is also a setter
 $location.path(path[0] + '/getusers');
 // $location.path() === '/myapp/getusers'

 // ------------------ \\

 // Shorter way
 $location.path($location.path() + '/getusers');
 // $location.path() === '/myapp/getusers'
```

Comment: If you are using angular in a non-single page application, this method is not reliable. e.g. calling ${contextPath}/api/delegation/apps.  The method above has no idea if the application has been redeployed to the root context or pages are called from various nested paths.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 2 (if using hashbang mode). Below code can be used to form the url.

```
document.location.href.substr(0, document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/#")) + "/getusers";
```

Inspired from  the answer of @jarek-krochmalski

Answer (score 1):

if you are using hashbang mode, with "#", you can do something like that:

```
$location.absUrl().substr(0, $location.absUrl().lastIndexOf("#")) + "/getusers"
```

Answer (score 1):

For AngularJS [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service you are good to go with `url : 'getusers'`, as follows:

```
$scope.postCall = function(obj) {
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'getusers',
                dataType : 'json',
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                data : obj,
            });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use injection in your controller like the following:

```
angular.module("yourModule").controller("yourController", ["$scope", "yourService", "$location", function($scope, yourService, $location){

....
      //here you can send the path value to your model.

      yourService.setPath($location.path());

....

}]);
```