# Spring + AngularJS -> getting the ContextPath

Tags: angularjs, spring

Im a Rookie in Angular JS.
I'm using the Spring MVC model and would like to get the contextPath from Tomcat (localthost:8080>>>/test<<<).

What I need is a variable that stores the value of "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" from a JSP and pass that variable to the config.

Is it possible to pass that value to the config? And if not: is there another or even better way?

Ive searched stackoverflow, but only found one answer but must confess I didn't understand it since it hadnt much code to go for: [Whats the better way to identify the context path in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022285/whats-the-better-way-to-identify-the-context-path-in-angular-js)

App.js

```
    (function() {
    var app = angular.module('testApp', [ 'ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : '/home',
        })
        ;
    });
}());
```

HomeController.java

```
 @Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String showHomereg(){
        return "content/index.jsp";
    }
```

The way its shown here will direct me to "localhost:8080/home" instead of "localhost:8080/test/home"

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to update your `$routeProvider` in `app.js` and add `/test` in when function.

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('testApp', [ 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/test', {
        templateUrl : '/home',
    });
});
});
```

Comment: This is not the solution, since the contextPath might be a different one on another server.
I need to give my angularJS app the contextPath from the JSP its coming from

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for relative paths. First of start by removing slash before home (client side):

`templateUrl : '/home',`
to:
`templateUrl : 'home',`

which obviously, will try to load something relative to the app it self e.g. if your SPA is say, index.html (or I would guess index.jsp?) in say webapp folder, then app will try to load template from webapp with that name. As this is a service (interesting concept here but IMHO unnecessary to do it as the app is already loaded in the browser) it will do a get *relative* to the app which might work (I assume that you tried that).

Again, 'home path a.k.a. /' is already loaded in the browser and is the starting html template.